# How to plot data points on top of what was previously plotted in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How to plot data points on top of what was previously plotted in MATLAB?

For example I have a 2D plot of a plane and points, and I plot
the points with scatter3 after I plot the plane with pcolor,
and the plane covers the points that are below it.

In the first image you can see the points by themselves. But when I plot
them together with the plane, the plane covers the points below it.

[image]

[image]

THanks

Comment: Post your code for these plots? I reckon your scatter3 is plotting in 3D and putting some of those points behind the z-value of the plane you're plotting

Comment: Thank you! I replaced scatter3 with scatter and it works now.

Comment: Maybe you can post this as a reply so that I can accept it as answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `scatter3` instead of `scatter` and it is plotting against the 3rd dimension linearly which is why the points disappear half way down. They are actually just behind your plane.

Answer (score 1):

[Use `uistack`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/207603/1121420) to bring data points on top of the plot of the plane. Something like

```
p1 = plot(...); % plot of data points (need to be on top of plane) 
hold on;
p2 = plot(...); % plot of the plane

uistack(p1);  % to bring data points on top of the plane
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `hold on`. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/hold.html for more information.

Comment: I do use hold on actually.

Comment: I edited my original post and added the pictures, please check it out.